# How do I make a specifically formatted dictionary from a csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonista

I've looked around on the internet but I haven't found anything that works.
I want to turn `dovah.csv` into a dictionary for a translator.

Is there a way to specifically format it like this?

```
english_to_dovahzul = {
  'the': 'faal',
  'quick': 'nel',
  'brown': 'prun',
  'fox': 'ilit'
}

dovahzul_to_english = {v: k for k, v in.english_to_dovahzul.items()}
```

Comment: Please attempt to do this yourself first and if that fails then ask your question. Otherwise if you are unable to even make a attempt then you are probably better off hiring a developer.

Comment: Try: [this](https://repl.it/repls/AttentiveMistyFilesize)

Comment: Thats why the question is here. Ive been trying,  and googling how to do it every chance i had, all day. Im new to python, ive been learning by doing and when i run into something i cant, i ask.

Comment: How is your csv data looks like ?

Comment: @Chandila07 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X6vtsGsdVSUp09m4aA1G7oy660KMr7E8

Comment: @Reconer_000 please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try any example from below two:

example 1: with file handling:

```
with open(filename) as stream:
    result={}
    for item in stream.readlines()[1:]:
        line = item.strip().split()
        result.update({line[0]:line[2]})    #line[i] is column index to create dict
print(result)
```

example 2: with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')
result = dict(zip(df["English Word"],df["Dragon Translation"]))  #df['column_name'] is column name to create dict
print(result)
```